# Invalid stream header in java when deserialize a xml string to an object

Tags: java, xml, deserialization

I have a small project. I want to deserialize a xml string to an object but i got an error "invalid stream header 3C3F786D" when create ObjectInputStream.

code:

```
   String value=" <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <metaData xmlns="....">
      <data key="aa">fdfdfd</data>
      <data key="bb">5.2.0.15947</data>
      <data key="tt">
        <ee SI="SIDocument">
        </ee>
      </data>
    </metaData>";



  ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes());
                    if(bi!=null)
                    {
                     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bi);// error here
                     MetaData metaData= (MetaData) in.readObject();
                    }
```

I've google and i know that, String.getBytes cannot use for  ObjectInputStream. 
So, how i can do that?

**Solved**

I have used JAXB to serialize. See
[JAXB tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html)

Comment: The idea is that is will read bytes created by `ObjectOutputStream` not some arbitrary String.

Comment: Indeed. If you want to deserialize XML, you should be using an XML deserializer, not `ObjectInputStream`.